# Dynamic change of the global clock in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to solve a problem that the user must  change dynamic from global clock the time,day,date,city. Can someone help me.The different ways are:
Sun
Sunday

28th March 2010
28 March 2010
28th Mar 2010
28 Mar 2010
28/03/2010
28th March 10
28 March 10
28th Mar 10
28 Mar 10
28/03/10
28th March
28 March
28th Mar
28 Mar
28/03

5:28:12 am
5:28 am
5:28:12
5:28
17:28:12
17:28

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want the default date format on a page to be able to be changed by a user?  I see you have other questions in the same vein, what have you tried so far?

Comment: So far I have a global clock but has not the proper display.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the **[Datejs library](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/)**? Among great parsing features it also has a fully customizable output format. Although from your question I don't know what exactly you try to accomplish, its likely that Datejs already solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Would using the toLocaleDateString and toLocaleTimeString options work?  They would then print out the date and time values as appropriate to the user's localization settings - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocaledatestring.asp